# Deleting images leaves empty placeholders that does not even exist (Android Studio)

Tags: android

I am developing an app which has some features for image handling too. For that I am creating a directory in the device's internal storage with path ***/CamScan/tempFiles*** in which I am storing images for a temporary basis while app is running. On back press when app is exiting, and also when app runs again, I am calling a deleteRecursive() method to delete the complete tempFiles directory (if it exists).

This is my deleteRecursive() method:

```
public void deleteRecursive(File file) {
        try {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                for (File child : file.listFiles())
                {
                    deleteRecursive(child);
                }
            }
            file.delete();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And this is how I am calling it onBackPressed and onCreateView:

```
File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/CamScan/tempFiles");
deleteRecursive(directory);
```

It is working fine for deleting the directory and its child on exit but after exiting the app I can still see a folder with name ***tempFiles*** in my gallery that has actually empty image placeholders (that complete black background which keeps loading if I click on it). If I navigate to my app's directory ***CamScan***, I don't see any directory with name ***tempFiles*** but it exists (with some empty placeholders) in the gallery.

In my app I have a grid view in which I am loading all the gallery images. These empty placeholders exists even there (its obvious as I am using MediaStore to get those images) but if select that placeholder and try to do any operation on it, it throws a FileNotFoundException (which is again obvious as the file does not exist in the storage).

***My Question:***
What is it that I am doing wrong. How can I avoid such errors, is there any solution to the problem or at-least an alternative to what I am doing.

Thank you

Comment: `file.delete();` , Check the return value as it might fail. `public void deleteRecursive(File file) ` Make that `public boolean deleteRecursive(File file) ` as then the caller can check the result. Display toasts if something goes wrong to infornm the user. Then also stop. `if (!file.delete() { Toast(...could not delete file..); return false;`

Comment: Indeed your code does delete nothing from MediaStore so gallery apps dont know about the deletes. So you have to start the media scanner for deleted files or derectories. Or reboot your device.

Comment: If I delete the folder containing images then won't it automatically update the deleted files in the gallery too. Is there is difference in deleting that folder manually and deleting it from the app?

Comment: Indeed that is different as you have seen.

Comment: Thanks for the help @blackapps. I got a solution, I changed the directory name to CamScan/.tempfiles (I made the tempfiles folder hidden). Now when I delete the folder, it gets removed from the storage and I don't see any empty placeholders also. I guess they exist even now also, but since the folder was hidden when I deleted it, those placeholders are not visible in my gallery